# ¿Como puedo obtener datos de una tabla con registros a otra tabla con foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

tengo una tabla con registros de calificaciones, pero quiero mostrar estos datos a otra tabla de calificaciones recientes que solo indique parcial, nombre y calificación.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el main/index.php está la otra tabla que quiero que se consulte con un foreach pero este me indica lo siguiente:

Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, float given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sge\view\main\index.php on line 150

```
<div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">Calificaciones Recientes</h3>
              <div class="card-tools">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                 </button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                 </button>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table id="tableCalificacionAlumno" class="table m-0">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th>Parcial</th>                                                    
                          <th>Materia</th>
                          <th>Calificación</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                       foreach ($calificacion as $calificacion) {
                    ?>
                       <tr>
                             <td><?php echo $calificacion['nombre_parcial'] ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $calificacion['nombre_materia'] ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $calificacion['calificación'] ?></td>
                       </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>                                        
                    </tbody>
                    <thead>                           
                    </thead>
                 </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.table-responsive -->
```

Este de aquí sería el script de esa parte, mando a llamar el controlador calificación y hago una consulta a readCalificacionAlumno:

```html
var mostrarCalificaciones = function() {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",

         async: false,
         url: "<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>calificacion/readCalificacionAlumno",
         dataType: 'json', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
         success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(ind, elem) {
               if (ind <= 9) {
                  var colorCalificacion = "";
                  if (elem.calificacion > 6) {
                     colorCalificacion = "success";
                  } else {
                     colorCalificacion = "danger";
                  }
                  var htmlTags = '<tr>' +              
                     '<td>' + elem.nombre_parcial + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + elem.nombre_materia + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + elem.calificacion + '</td>' +
                     '<td> <span class="badge badge-' + colorCalificacion + '">' + elem.calificacion + '</span></td>' +
                     '</tr>';
                  $('#tableCalificacionAlumno tbody').append(htmlTags);
               }
            });
         },
      });
   }
```

Este es el modelo de readCalificacionAlumno:

```
public function readCalificacionAlumno()
{
    $id_alumno = $_SESSION['id'];
    require_once 'calificacionDTO.php';
    $query = " SELECT calificacion.*, profesor.*, alumno.*, parcial.*, materia.* FROM calificacion calificacion, profesor profesor, alumno alumno, parcial parcial, materia materia WHERE calificacion.id_profesor = profesor.id_profesor AND calificacion.id_alumno = alumno.id_alumno AND calificacion.id_parcial = parcial.id_parcial AND calificacion.id_materia = materia.id_materia AND alumno.id_alumno = '" . $id_alumno . "'";
    $objCalificaciones = array();
    if (is_array($this->db->consultar($query)) || is_object($this->db->consultar($query))) {
        foreach ($this->db->consultar($query) as $key => $value) {
            $calificacion = new CalificacionDTO();
            $calificacion->id_calificacion = $value['id_calificacion'];
            $calificacion->id_profesor = $value['id_profesor'];
            $calificacion->id_alumno = $value['id_alumno'];
            $calificacion->id_parcial = $value['id_parcial'];
            $calificacion->id_materia = $value['id_materia'];
            $calificacion->calificacion = $value['calificacion'];
            $calificacion->observacion_calificacion = $value['observacion_calificacion'];
            $calificacion->fecha_calificacion = $value['fecha_calificacion'];
            $calificacion->nombre_profesor = $value['nombre_profesor'];
            $calificacion->appaterno_profesor = $value['appaterno_profesor'];
            $calificacion->apmaterno_profesor = $value['apmaterno_profesor'];
            $calificacion->nombre_alumno = $value['nombre_alumno'];
            $calificacion->appaterno_alumno = $value['appaterno_alumno'];
            $calificacion->apmaterno_alumno = $value['apmaterno_alumno'];
            $calificacion->nombre_parcial = $value['nombre_parcial'];
            $calificacion->nombre_materia = $value['nombre_materia'];
            $_SESSION['id_calificacion'] = $value['id_calificacion'];
            $_SESSION['calificacion'] = $value['calificacion'];
            $_SESSION['observacion_calificacion'] = $value['observacion_calificacion'];
            $_SESSION['nombre_materia'] = $value['nombre_materia'];
            array_push($objCalificaciones, $calificacion);
        }
    } else {
        $objCalificaciones = null;
    }

    return $objCalificaciones;
}
```

Comment: Claro, por que estas haciendo un **for each** de nuevo en el html pero de que?, si no hay nada que recorrer, se supone que en la petición Ajax ya estas procesando la data que te devuelve, solo deberías indicar en que parte del DOM vas a pintar la informacion.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por responder, entonces como podría traer esos datos a la segunda tabla?

Comment: Mira creo que la mejor opción es devolver un **JSON** y procesarlo en el _succes_ de _Ajax_, recuerda que para que Ajax reconozca o tome la respuesta de PHP debe estar después de un **echo**. Decide si procesar la información en Ajax (mas complejo) o enviar la estructura realizada por PHP, dame un rato y pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias amigo, es que debo hacerlo por Ajax para que me muestre toda la tabla, pero en el success pongo un console.log pero no me devuelve nada.

Comment: Como te mencione, Ajax reconoce la data con un **echo** de PHP